# changing value from function

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers

I want to change a 2dim char array in a function.

I allocate the space like

```
char **u;
u = new char * [ MAX_DEPTH ];
for (i=0; i<MAX_DEPTH; i++)
    u[ i ] = new char [ BUFFER_SIZE ];
```

the function looks like

```
rem(char ***arr, int max_length, char *url)
{
    int idx=0;
    char * p;
    int i;

    p = strtok (url,"/"); 

    while (p != NULL && idx < max_length)
    {

        for (  i=0; i<maxUrlSize-1 && p[i] != '\0'; i++)
            (*arr)[idx][i] = p[i];
        for (     ; i< maxUrlSize-1; i++)
            (*arr)[idx][i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

the function will be used in my main program.

```
rem( &u, MAX_LEN, url);
```

but after leaving the function there is nothing in. Could someone explain me how to use pointers in this way?

Comment: There;s nothing obviously wrong, but more than 1-line fragments would really help - we have to infer that the function implementation is rem(char ***tmp, int ?) for the code to even begin to make sense.

Comment: The code you posted is all correct.

Comment: From the function, this code looks absolutely fine. Could u please provide the code on how you are invoking this method from other parts of the program.

Comment: @Roby: Please edit and align your code. One of the members took the pains for doing it for you the first time,You should learn it from there...Can't have a endless loop of your edits & then counter edits to make it readable.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code in `rem`, what you have looks OK. However, unless you are reallocating the space assigned to `u` inside the function `rem`, you don't really need to pass `&u` here. Just pass `u` instead. The receiving parameter `tmp` should just be `char **`, and you would access it as `tmp[i][j]`.  EDIT to comment: What is `tmp`? Looks like a global.

Comment: @Als: i will try it :P new on this site :) thx

Comment: Joe: im sorry tmp is array i removed some lines of code because there arent important to post...

Comment: @Roby: Sure :) Welcome and wish you happy learning.

Comment: @Roby: why not pass the `u` as `rem (u, MAX_LEN, url)` , and simplify the extra pointer `***`` in yout `rem` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the reference to `tmp` in your function, to `arr`. You aren't accessing the parameter `arr` at all.   Also, you do not need `char ***` here, since you aren't changing the space allocated to `u`.  Instead, you should have parameter `char **arr`, which you access as `arr[i][j]`.  And you should then pass `u` to `rem`, rather than `&u`.

Comment: you are right, i removed some lines of code and paste it together... tmp is arr ... im sorry used the wrong name :-/